# Pre-calculus: Dealing with negative indeces

Tags: algebra-precalculus

can someone please show me how to solve problems such as these? Obviously, I was able to find a basic principle for the first questions, but I couldn't apply this to the others. I want to learn the 'method' on systematically solving these.

[image: ](![a busy cat]

Comment: If these comments help you, mark one as the answer or add some questions, please

Answer (score 1):

There a 'law': $$x^{a}\times x^{b}=x^{a+b}$$ And another one:
$$x^{0}=1$$ Applying this on e.g. (b) results in: $$x^{-6}\times x^{6}=x^{-6+6}=x^{0}=1$$
Dividing both sides by $x^{6}$ leads to the conclusion that: $$x^{-6}=\frac{1}{x^{6}}$$ Also there is a 'law': $$\left(x^{a}\right)^{b}=x^{ab}$$ Applying
that on e.g. (o) results in: $$\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-5}=\left(x^{-1}\right)^{-5}=x^{\left(-1\right)\left(-5\right)}=x^{5}$$
If you really want to get hold on this then it is essential is to **get familiar with these laws**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're just supposed to flip all the fractions. You can use, for arbitrary elements (e.g. variables, polynomials, numbers) $X,Y$ and $\alpha>0$,
$$
\left(\frac XY\right)^{-\alpha}=\left[\left(\frac XY\right)^{-1}\right]^\alpha=\left(\frac YX\right)^\alpha.
$$